# how to install pypylon in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: computer-vision, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am very new to the Raspberry Pi. I am having Raspberry Pi 4 (ARM 32-bit hard-float) and Raspbian. I am having Basler Camera (GigE Interface) and wanted to use it in my Python-OpenCV script. I have already managed to get videos using a pylon viewer in Raspberry pi. How I can install PyPylon in my Raspberry PI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you figured this out.  It looks like in the last 6 months or so Basler added Linux support to pypylon.  Pypylon is the unofficial python wrapper for the C++ based SDK which allows you to develop applications for Basler GigE cameras.

before installing Pypylon, make sure you are using python 3 (they don't support 2.7 anymore) and have installed and fully updated pip.  If you have captured images it sounds like you have pylon viewer working so you know the camera drivers are installed properly.

Here is the link to the pypylon binaries: https://github.com/Basler/pypylon/releases there are also some instructions on gitub for building from source which requires swig.  When I set up my system pypylon was not available on linux yet so i have not done this process yet.  It's been a month since you posted so if you have worked this out, i'd be interested in knowing how it went.  I would like to do the same thing.